# Need to write oracle sql query to extract 2 dates parsing string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to parse a string to extract dates for the sample text(sometime date format changes too) as below:

Need Date that comes after POP or Period of Performance word in 2 columns

### Result:

```
start date:10/1/2018
end date:9/30/2019
```

### Sample Text:

```
Facility:XYZ Location: NYC           
Lease date: 10/1/2020- 9/30/2020
Lessor: Edgewater Industrial Park LLC
Period of Performance: 10/1/2018- 9/30/2019
Schedule: region: xyz
```

OR

```
Location: NY 
LeasedateL 10/1/2020- 9/30/2020
Lessor: Edgewater Industrial Park LLC
PoP 10/1/2018- 9/30/2019
Schedule: region: xyz
```

Comment: you tag oracle11g and oracle10g at the same time, which one are you actually using?

Comment: I just found a record that has text with below line, just one date and POP through is the beginning

POP through 07/31/2019

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression can help extract the date parts

```
SQL> with t as
  2  ( select '
  3  Facility:ASAHSN Location: LaGuardia NY
  4  Lease Number:26DDDKKD-55
  5  Lessor: Edgewater Industrial Park LLC
  6  Period of Performance: 10/1/2018- 9/30/2019
  7  Schedule: region: xyz' txt
  8  from dual
  9  )
 10  select
 11    regexp_substr(txt,'[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{4}.*[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{4}')
 12  from t;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(TXT,'[
--------------------
10/1/2018- 9/30/2019
```

and you can then continue from there to get each date, eg

```
SQL> with t as
  2  ( select '
  3  Facility:ASAHSN Location: LaGuardia NY
  4  Lease Number:26DDDKKD-55
  5  Lessor: Edgewater Industrial Park LLC
  6  Period of Performance: 10/1/2018- 9/30/2019
  7  Schedule: region: xyz' txt
  8  from dual
  9  ),
 10  t1 as
 11  (
 12  select
 13    regexp_substr(txt,'[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{4}.*[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{4}') dates
 14  from t
 15  )
 16  select
 17    substr(dates,1,instr(dates,'-')-1),
 18    substr(dates,instr(dates,'-')+1)
 19  from t1;

SUBSTR(DA SUBSTR(DAT
--------- ----------
10/1/2018  9/30/2019
```

and then apply TO_DATE as you need

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, actually  text can have mutliple types of dates so I have to pick date that either starts with POP or Period of Performace, how can I achieve it

Comment: It is always going to come down to just altering the regular expression to identify the appropriate elements you need. Full docs here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm